# Zend element decorator

Tags: php, zend-framework, decorator

I created an element submit:

```
   $this->addElement('submit', 'button', array(
        'ignore'   => true,
        'label'    => 'Update',
        'class' => 'btn blue',
    ));
```

And now try to set for this element decorator:

```
    $submit = $this->getElement('submit');
    $submit->setDecorators(array(
        array('ViewHelper'),
        array('Description'),
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'div', 'class'=>'submit-group')),
    ));
```

Something is wrong in my code because I get fatal error that I call member function `setDecorators` on no object?

Comment: You do have trailing commas in both of your statements..

Comment: I think problem is not in comma

Comment: Probably not, but it's bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you either need to change:

`$submit = $this->getElement('submit');`

to

`$submit = $this->getElement('button');`

OR

```
$this->addElement('submit', 'button', array(
    'ignore'   => true,
    'label'    => 'Update',
    'class' => 'btn blue',
));
```

to

```
$this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
    'ignore'   => true,
    'label'    => 'Update',
    'class' => 'btn blue',
));
```

It appears the first parameter for addElement is the `element type` and the second parameter is the `element id`. Not the other way around.

And, getElement needs to take in that `element id` for it to work, not the `element type`

See here for more information: http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.10/_Form.html#Zend_Form::addElement()
http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.10/_Form.html#Zend_Form::getElement()